# Ruby finding data type of keys in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that is built very differently depending on what is in a yaml file. these are the two possible constructs.

```
config = {'points' => {2012 => 5.5, 2013 => 6.3}}

config = {'points' => {'method' => 'calculate_periodicaly', 'default' => 10}}
```

The first one will always have dates as keys and the second will have a method and a default key.

I would like to pass it to a method depending on how it was built. i have something like this to find out if it has years for keys

```
config.is_a?(Hash) && config['points'].has_key?(2012) && config['points'].has_key?(2013)
=> true
```

And i could do something similar for for the other way it gets built. But to me this is ugly code. I would like to do something where it can figure out the datatype of each key. So if all the keys are numeric then it should be the date hash, if all the keys are strings then it should be a string hash.

i tried something like this

```
config.is_a?(Hash) && config['points'].keys.each {|key| key.is_a? Integer}
```

but this just returns

```
=> [
   [0] 2012,
   [1] 2013
]
```

Is there a better way of doing this? a more Ruby way of doing it perhaps?

**UPDATE**

the reason we check that its a hash is that sometimes it can be called as a literal as well. here is a bit of the yaml

```
 homeowner_policies:
  total: active_homeowne
  actual: qualifing_homeowner
  points: 
    method: calculated_points_by_selected_policies
    default: 0
  target: homeowner_industry_target_agaist_market_share
  description: Property / Homeowners
```

This example it will build points into a hash with `method` and `default` being keys. The gem that renders what's in the hash. but if you just want to specify a direct amount you can specify something like this

```
 homeowner_policies:
  conditional: include_homeowner?
  total: active_homeowne
  actual: qualifing_homeowner
  points: 10
  target: homeowner_industry_target_agaist_market_share
  description: Property / Homeowners
```

and then the third possibility is points by year so like the first example but you can reffer to years and each year can give different points.

where this will be used is in deciding what method should use the data.

If the points are based off years then a method called `requires_parsing?` within a class will return true and that class will parse the data. if not then another class will etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `all?` instead each:

```
config.is_a?(Hash) && config['points'].keys.all? {|key| key.is_a? Integer}
```

Note: Is there any reason why you're checking if config is a Hash? If it comes from yml file than this is redundant.

To tell whether there is a better way to do this, you would need to show the method you want pass this to and exactly how you are planning on calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to do it (which obviously has broad application).

**Code**

```
def confirm_key_type(h, key, klass)
  h[key].keys.all? { |k| klass === k } rescue nil
end
```

or

```
def confirm_key_type(h, key, klass)
  begin
    h[key].keys.all? { |k| klass === k }
  rescue
    nil
  end
end
```

The first form is called "inline rescue".  It is loved by some, [hated by others](http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/why-rescue-nil-is-bad). In the second form you could of course rescue relevant exceptions only (`NoMethodError`, `TypeError`, etc.).

The block could alternatively be written `{ |k| k.class == k }` or `{ |k| k.is_a? k }`.

**Examples**

```
config = {'points' => {2012 => 5.5, 2013 => 6.3}}
  #=> {"points"=>{2012=>5.5, 2013=>6.3}}

confirm_key_type(config, 'points', Fixnum)     #=> true
confirm_key_type(config, 'points', String)     #=> false

config = {'points' => {'method' => 'calculate_periodicaly', 'default' => 10}}
  #=> {"points"=>{"method"=>"calculate_periodicaly", "default"=>10}}

confirm_key_type(config, 'points', Fixnum)     #=> false
confirm_key_type(config, 'points', String)     #=> true

confirm_key_type(config, 'cats', Fixnum)       #=> nil
confirm_key_type(config, :dogs, String)        #=> nil

confirm_key_type([1,2,3], 'points', Fixnum)    #=> nil
confirm_key_type('goldfish', 'points', String) #=> nil
confirm_key_type(nil, 'points', String)        #=> nil
```